# Prueba o test de COVID

Tags: vocabulario, expresiones

Quería preguntaros qué forma es la correcta.
¿Se dice *hacerse prueba de COVID*, o más bien *hacerse test de COVID*? ¿O existe alguna expresión mejor?

Answer (score 5):

La Fundéu tiene un [artículo](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/test/) que trata este tema directamente:

> Cabe recordar que el [diccionario académico](https://dle.rae.es/?w=test&m=form&o=h) define ***test*** únicamente como ‘**prueba destinada a evaluar conocimientos o aptitudes**, en la cual hay que elegir la respuesta correcta entre varias opciones previamente fijadas’ o, en el ámbito de la psicología, ‘prueba psicológica para estudiar alguna función’.
>
> No obstante, de acuerdo con lo recogido por diccionarios como el *Clave*, el *Diccionario del español actual* o el *Diccionario del estudiante*, *test* ha dejado de designar únicamente una evaluación psicológica para pasar a referirse a **cualquier tipo de prueba**, como demuestran los *test de embarazo* o los *test de alcoholemia*.
>
> Por último, aunque la palabra *test* aparece recogida en los principales diccionarios del español, conviene recordar que existen **alternativas** de sentido similar, como *prueba*, *cuestionario*, *examen*, *análisis* (en el ámbito médico) o *control*.

Es decir, el DLE admite solo *prueba* para el sentido médico, pero otros diccionarios ya recogen el uso de la palabra *test* para referirse a pruebas médicas o de cualquier otro tipo.

Answer (score 3):

Según la RAE, la palabra [test](https://dle.rae.es/test) significa:

> 1. m. Prueba destinada a evaluar conocimientos o aptitudes, en la cual hay que elegir la respuesta correcta entre varias opciones previamente fijadas.

Por lo que se entiende que va más enfocado a pruebas no médicas

Caso contrario sería la palabra [prueba](https://dle.rae.es/prueba) que dice:

> 6. f. Análisis médico.

Así que sería correcto decir "*hacerse prueba de COVID*"

Answer (score 2):

En castellano, aunque se vea la expresión *test de COVID* con cierta frecuencia, es preferible usar *prueba de COVID*. El motivo es que la palabra *test*, aunque aceptada, tiene un significado más restringido. En general, solo debe usarse con el significado de *prueba psicológica* o el de *examen en el que se ofrecen varias opciones de respuesta para cada pregunta*; en este último caso, al menos en España, es más normal hablar de *examen de tipo test*.

Además, falta un artículo en las opciones que nos das. Entiendo que para una persona cuya lengua materna es eslava los artículos son bastante difíciles de usar correctamente. Pero la mejor opción es *hacerse una prueba de COVID*.

Answer (score 1):

La pagina [Pruebas de COVID-19](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pruebas_de_COVID-19) de Wikipedia contiene tambien la palabra *test* (solo tres veces). Prueba seria mejor.